# error: java.lang.RuntimeException, How to preperly get extras from an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to set an Intent between two layouts:

```
searchListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        long id = listOfDrugs.get(i).getId();
        Intent detailsDrugIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrugDetails.class);
        detailsDrugIntent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(detailsDrugIntent);
    }
});
```

and to call its extras this way:

```
id = Long.parseLong(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("id")); // THIS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
```

Proceeding this way trigger this error message:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mypharmacy.app/com.mypharmacy.app.DrugDetails}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

How to fix this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
id = this.getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id", 1L);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Extras in other activity just like this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) 
   {
     long value = extras.getLong("id");
   }
```